# iphone resume application on UILocalNotification

Tags: ios4, uilocalnotification

I've managed to get the application I'm writing to present a UILocalNotification when it is in the background. Though when the application resumes, the user interface becomes inactive.

Is anyone aware of how to get the application responding again having resumed from the background state?

Thanks,
Matt.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and found that the answer is to not set up your notifications while in debug.  Instead make sure your app has quit fully, launch it from the homescreen and then set the notifications.